# Eclipselink - ConcurrentModification Exception while em.find

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, concurrentmodification

I am experiencing ConcurrentModificationException while having a read operation on an entity using EntityManager.find or Query.getResultList methods every now and then. I am using version 2.3.2 for EclipseLink. I have removed explicit EntityManager refresh and flush after getting a clue from post https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=229581 and there is no change in the behaviour, i still get the below exception.

**StrackTrace looks something like that:**

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.InterfaceContainerPolicy.next(InterfaceContainerPolicy.java:274)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ContainerPolicy.next(ContainerPolicy.java:1116)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.WriteLockManager.traverseRelatedLocks(WriteLockManager.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.WriteLockManager.acquireLockAndRelatedLocks(WriteLockManager.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.WriteLockManager.checkAndLockObject(WriteLockManager.java:449)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.WriteLockManager.traverseRelatedLocks(WriteLockManager.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.WriteLockManager.acquireLockAndRelatedLocks(WriteLockManager.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.WriteLockManager.acquireLocksForClone(WriteLockManager.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.cloneAndRegisterObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:971)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.cloneAndRegisterObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:929)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkIdentityMapAccessor.getAndCloneCacheKeyFromParent(UnitOfWorkIdentityMapAccessor.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkIdentityMapAccessor.getFromIdentityMap(UnitOfWorkIdentityMapAccessor.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.IdentityMapAccessor.getFromIdentityMap(IdentityMapAccessor.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerExistingObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3899)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectBuildingQuery.registerIndividualResult(ObjectBuildingQuery.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadObjectQuery.java:780)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkEarlyReturn(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:802)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:781)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:418)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1128)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:485)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:734)
```

---

The below is how my class looks like that throws the ConcurrentModificationException at random times, there are no definite steps to reproduce the issue. There are other methods as well.

```
@Stateless
@Local
@EJB(name = "java:global/framework/admin/AdminServicePersistence", beanInterface = AdminrServicePersistence.class) 
public class AdminServicePersistenceImpl implements AdminServicePersistence {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "AdminServicePU")
    protected EntityManager em;

    protected void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    } 

    @Override
    public AdminPE findAdminById(final Long id, final boolean refresh)    throws AdminServiceModuleException {
        try {
            final TypedQuery<AdminPE> query = em.createNamedQuery(AdminPE.ADMIN_BY_ID, AdminPE.class);
            query.setParameter("id", id);
            if(refresh) {
                query.setHint(QueryHints.REFRESH, HintValues.TRUE);
            }
            return executeSingleResultQuery(query);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            throw new AdminServiceModuleException(AdminError.PERSISTENCE_QUERY_ERROR, exc);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using an EntityManager in multiple threads?   The only way I can see this occurring is if an EntityManager is somehow reused amongst different threads - each thread needs its own EntityManager and query instances.

Comment: @Chris, I agree with you on the fact that it can only happen when different threads are using the same instance of an EntityManager. I believe this is not true in my case and  also this just happens at random. I personally expect the framework "Eclipselink" to handle this concurrency issue.

Comment: Are you using read-only instances or any other optimizations in other threads?

Comment: @Chris No not really. Well i can say that this scenario occurs more frequently in my case when i am deleting stuff and in between there are queries that fetch data from database and all this is part of one single transaction.

Comment: Turns out to be that the Admin entity has bi-directional many-to-many relationship with Group entity that causes this exception to occur. When i disable the relationship things work perfectly :(.